# Reconfiguring Ctrl on a MacBook Pro's keyboard to another key

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, keybindings

I have a problem with the left <kbd>⇧</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> on my MacBook Pro (mid 2012).

I can use the right <kbd>⇧</kbd> but since there's only one <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, I was wondering because there are two <kbd>⌥</kbd> buttons and two <kbd>⌘</kbd> buttons, if I could reconfigure one of them to replace the control feature.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please define your issue, will a replacement of keys work? What did you do with your keyboard?

Comment: He did not do anything to his keyboard. There is only one Ctrl on MB-keyboards. He wonders why there are two shift, two apple and two alt keys.

Answer (score 1):

Install [KeyRemap4MacBook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en), save a file like this as `~/Library/Application Support/KeyRemap4MacBook/private.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::OPTION_R, KeyCode::CONTROL_R</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Then open the KeyRemap4MacBook application, press the ReloadXML button, and enable the setting.